# GAE Task queue wont continue if specific value in dropdown selected

Tags: javascript, php, google-app-engine, drop-down-menu, task-queue

I have a form, when submitted passes the data to a taskqueue.php, which then goes on to pass the values to the process.php.

Heres the dropdown thats causing the issue:

```
<select id="year" name='year'>
<option value="0">Year End...*</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```

If I select 2015, no issues, it will continue on to taskqueue.php then processing.php and perform the task. If I select 2014 or 2013, then I get a blank page with the url looking like its stuck at the taskqueue.php.

If I change all of the ‘values’ of the dropdown to 2015, then it will go ahead and process the task e.g

```
<option value="2015">2013</option>
<option value="2015">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
```

if I change the dropdown label, theres no issues, just seems to be the value itself.

I do have javascript that hides/shows dropdowns but i cant see anywhere that references 2014/2013 specifically.

See code below
FORM:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function display_Field(e){
        document.getElementById('month').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('quarter').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('year').style.display = "none";
        periodend=document.getElementById('periodend').value;
       if (periodend === 'Monthly') { 
        document.getElementById('year').selectedIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById('month').style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById('year').style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById('quarter').selectedIndex = 0;
       } 
       if(periodend === 'Quarterly') { 
       document.getElementById('year').selectedIndex = 0;
       document.getElementById('quarter').style.display = "inline";
       document.getElementById('year').style.display = "inline";
       document.getElementById('month').selectedIndex = 0;
       } 
       if (periodend === 'Yearly'){
        document.getElementById('year').selectedIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById('year').style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById('month').selectedIndex = 0;
        document.getElementById('quarter').selectedIndex = 0;
        } 
    }
    function validate() {
        periodend=document.getElementById('periodend').value;
        month=document.getElementById('month').value;
        quarter=document.getElementById('quarter').value;
        year=document.getElementById('year').value;
        if (periodend==='0'||(periodend==='Monthly' && (month==='0'||year==='0'))||(periodend==='Quarterly' && (quarter==='0'||year==='0'))||(periodend==='Yearly' && year==='0')) {
            valid_alert='';
            if (periodend==='0') {
                valid_alert='Please select a period end\n';
            }
            if (periodend==='Monthly' && (month==='0'||year==='0')) {
                if (month==='0') {
                valid_alert=valid_alert+'Please select a month end\n';
                }
                if (year==='0') {
                valid_alert=valid_alert+'Please select a year\n';
                }
            }
            if (periodend==='Quarterly' && (quarter==='0'||year==='0')) {
                if (quarter==='0') {
                valid_alert=valid_alert+'Please select a quarter end\n';
                }
                if (year==='0') {
                valid_alert=valid_alert+'Please select a year\n';
                }
            }
            if (periodend==='Yearly' && year==='0') {
                valid_alert=valid_alert+'Please select a year\n';
                }
            alert(valid_alert);
        return false;
        } else {
        return true;
        }
    }
    </script>

    <?php 
<form id="report-form" name="report-form" action="/taskqueue.php" method="post" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
    <select id="periodend" name="periodend" class="inline" onChange="display_Field(this.selectedIndex);">
                                    <option value="0">Period Ended...*</option>
                                    <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                                    <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
                                    <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>          
                                </select>
                                <select id="month" name='month'>
                                    <option value="0">Month End...*</option>
                                    <option value="January">January</option>
                                    <option value="February">February</option>
                                    <option value="March">March</option>
                                    <option value="April">April</option>
                                    <option value="May">May</option>
                                    <option value="June">June</option>
                                    <option value="July">July</option>
                                    <option value="August">August</option>
                                    <option value="September">September</option>
                                    <option value="October">October</option>
                                    <option value="November">November</option>
                                    <option value="December">December</option>
                                </select>
                                <select id="quarter" name='quarter'>
                                    <option value="0">Quarter End...*</option>
                                    <option value="30 September">30 September</option>
                                    <option value="31 December">31 December</option>
                                    <option value="31 March">31 March</option>
                                    <option value="30 June">30 June</option>                    
                                </select>
                                <select id="year" name='year'>
                                    <option value="0">Year End...*</option>
                                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                    <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                    <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                </select>
    <input type="submit" id="save-submit" name="save-submit" value="Save & Setup Another" onClick="return validate();"></form>
    >?
```

TASKQUEUE.PHP

```
<?php
require_once 'google/appengine/api/taskqueue/PushTask.php';
use google\appengine\api\taskqueue\PushTask;

$name=$current_user->businessname;
$staff_member=$current_user->user_firstname." ".$current_user->user_lastname;
$staff_email=$user_email;
$client_name=stripslashes($_POST['search']);
$periodend=$_POST['periodend'];
$month=$_POST['month'];
$quarter=$_POST['quarter'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];
$setupanother=$_POST['save-submit'];
$submit=$_POST['submit'];

if($_POST['save-submit'] || $_POST['submit']){
$wp_task = new PushTask('/process.php', ['name' => $name
, 'staff_member' => $staff_member
, 'client_name' => $client_name
, 'staff_email' => $staff_email
, 'periodend' => $periodend
, 'month' => $month
, 'quarter' => $quarter
, 'year' => $year
, 'comments' => $comments
, 'save-submit' => $setupanother
, 'submit' => $submit
]);
$task_name = $wp_task->add();
    }
header("Location: /<another page>");
    ?>
```

Anything you see that could be an issue? Thanks in advance, and sorry for the longwinded question, had to make sure i included everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

it was the `$year` variable in both my taskqueue.php AND processing.php that was the issue. Changed it to `$yearend` and seems to work. Hopefully thats the end of it!

Answer (score 0):

So looks like I overlooked the fact that there was another id 'year' in my style.css. So all i did was changed `'year'` in my code to `'yearend'`

EDIT:
So changing it to 'yearend', has allowed the code to loop back to the original page e.g. `header("Location: /<another page>");` doesnt give a blank page anymore, but still wont process the task in the background unless its '2015'. Just sits in the task queue.